# Setting write permissions on godaddy hosting

Tags: asp.net, automation, hosting, nant

I have godaddy asp.net hosting. Every time I upload the build, it’s a manual laborious task of setting write permissions (to folders) through the web interface.

Is this any way to automate this using NAnt?

Comment: Do the rights you can set through FTP reflect the rights you set in the webinterface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NAnt `<attrib>` task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/help/tasks/attrib.html) can do this.

```
<!-- readonly="false" is default - for clarity only -->
<attrib readonly="false">
  <fileset basedir="C:\foo">
    <include name="**/*" />
  </fileset>
</attrib>
```